# Is version specific style items required when using AppCompact?

Tags: android, styles, android-appcompat

Please check the option 1 and option 2, what is the advantage of defining platform specific style attributes like `android:colorPrimary` in values-v21 styles.

**values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="CommonTheme">

    </style>

    <style name="CommonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Option 1 : values-v21/styles.xml** - Using AppCompact for all the versions by inheritance.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="CommonTheme">
        <!-- All customization of the theme for this version -->
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Option 2 : values-v21/styles.xml** - Writing platform specific styles attributes along with inheritance.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="CommonTheme">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I see both options in different places,Which is better? Do we get any advantage in option 2.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2 is entirely unnecessary as AppCompat itself copies the colors over as seen in its [values-v21 theme](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml#94):

```
<!-- Copy our color theme attributes to the framework -->
<item name="android:colorPrimary">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:colorControlNormal">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
<item name="android:colorControlActivated">?attr/colorControlActivated</item>
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">?attr/colorControlHighlight</item>
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">?attr/colorButtonNormal</item>
```